# how to print only "cmd" from ps command using perl

Tags: perl, ps

I need to extract the cmd from the output of `ps`. I know that I can use the following to write only the PID using the `ps` command:

```sh
ps ax | perl -nle 'print $1 if /^ *([0-9]+)/'
```

I am wondering if I could write only the command using something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
ps axhw -o cmd
```

- `h` disables headers.
- `w` prevents the output from being truncated.
- `-o cmd` identifies which fields to output.

See also the `c` output modifier.